# Increase Firebase Apps per project Quota

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform

We have created a Firebase project in which we have added 30 (iOS, Android) apps, we try to add more apps into the project but we can't because firebase is saying "You've reached the limit of 30 apps in this project.". then after we checked the firebase FAQ in which they mention that "you can request an app limit increase via the Google Cloud Console".

On Google cloud console in Quotas management, we are trying to increase the quota of the "Firebase Apps per project" but we are getting this message "quota limit between 0 and 30".

[image: Check attached screenshot]

Getting this error if we trying to enter any number greater than 30:

[image: Getting this error if we trying to enter any number greater than 30]

What should we do next to solve this problem?

Comment: Contact support https://cloud.google.com/support

Comment: *firebaser here* As Martheen said, reaching out to support is best for now. I'm also asking around why you can't request the increase from the console, as that flow is supposed to work too.

Answer (score 2):

*firebaser here*

It looks like the option to request an increase is only available for projects that are on the Blaze plan. We've just clarified that in the FAQ too.

Despite that requirement, use of FCM will still be completely free.

Note that this is a **request** for a increase of the number of apps that are allowed on the project, so there's no guarantee that it will be granted.

Comment: It worked, we have upgraded the plan now we are able to increase the quota but while submitting the request we are getting "Quota request for Firebase Management API service failed. Please try again later." this error.

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure what's going on there. It might be best to [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.